width not divisible by 2
greetings blender community,
I get this error message when trying to render a video :

this should not have happened as my resolution is 1000px X 1000px and the % below is at 100 but here the error message indicates : 997x994. What is this due to and how I can fix this ?

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

We can see below your render settings that you have a render region with cropping enabled:

Render region is usually set up by hitting ⎈ CtrlB in the viewport and drawing a rectangle to limit the render preview to an area, but it also affects the final render:

There are three ways to go from there:

redo the region all around the camera view, or press ⎈ Ctrl⎇ AltB to remove the region entirely
uncheck the cropping checkbox if you want to keep the render region but not have it crop the final image
uncheck the render region checkbox if you want no render region affecting anything at all but want to keep the region saved for later use.

That being said, the other solution could also be to not use a video format as you render out. There are several cons about it, I went in depth in this other answer you probably should read if you aren't familiar with CGI rendering in general:
Video vs image output and recommendations

the first solution helped me to fix the problem, thank you
